# Using mpi subrouine changes value of variable

Tags: fortran, mpi

I have a problem with mpi + fortran.
Namely, one variable in my program is changed after using mpi subroutine MPI_RECV, though this variable sould not be changed.
Here the fragment of my code, where this trouble is:

```
IF ( RANK .EQ. 1 ) THEN
    CALL MPI_SEND (     &
        YDOT ( 1 ),     &
        1,              &
        MPI_DP_VEC,     &
        0,              &
        1,              &
        MPI_COMM_WORLD, &
        IERROR          &
                  )
END IF
IF ( RANK .EQ. 0 ) THEN
    PRINT *, rho, 'aaa1'
    CALL MPI_RECV (     &
        YDOT ( 1 ),     &
        1,              &
        MPI_DP_VEC,     &
        1,              &
        1,              &
        MPI_COMM_WORLD, &
        STATUS,         &
        IERROR          &
                  )
    PRINT *, rho, 'aaa2'
END IF
```

This yields

```
35368.254799414455      aaa1
2.1219957914593380E-314 aaa2
```

I use a derived data type MPI_DP_VEC, if it matters.
So, my question, why may it be?
Why does using subroutine MPI_RECV causes variable 'rho' to change?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Welcome, please read [ask] and [mcve], the code you show is completely insufficient. Please check that your status variable is of the right arrays size `MPI_STATUS_SIZE` or even better just try to use use `MPI_STATUS_IGNORE`  instead of your `STATUS`. We have many duplicates about this common problem. After that check the types of all other arguments. Use `use mpi` and not `include "mpif.h"` to get better diagnostics.

Comment: I closed it as a duplicate for the time being. Please check if the answers apply. If not, you have to show us **much** more information and a complete piece of code.

Comment: @VladimirF yes, your recommendation to use MPI_STATUS_IGNORE instead of STATUS was helpful. Thank you!

Comment: You most likely declared `STATUS` as `INTEGER :: STATUS` rather than `INTEGER, DIMENSION(MPI_STATUS_SIZE) :: STATUS`.

Comment: @HristoIliev yes, but using MPI_STATUS_IGNORE instead of STATUS in MPI_RECV have helped.